# How to efficiently convert from two __m128d to one __m128i in MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, x86, 64-bit, sse, mmx

Is converting then shifting then bitwise-or'ing the only way to convert from two `__m128d` to a single `__m128i`?

This is perfectly acceptable to Xcode in an x64 build

```
m128d v2dHi = ....
m128d v2dLo = ....
__m128i v4i = _mm_set_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_pi32(v2dHi), _mm_cvtpd_pi32(v2dLo))
```

and the disassembly shows `_mm_cvtpd_pi32` being used. However, Visual Studio cannot compile this, complaining about a linker error. This is supported in the VS docs, saying `_mm_cvtpd_pi32` is not supported on x64.

I'm not too worried that it's not available, but is two conversions, a shift, then a bitwise-or the fastest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got a linker error, you're probably ignoring a warning about an undeclared intrinsic function.

Your current code has a high risk of compiling to terrible asm.  If it compiled to a vector-shift and an OR, it already is compiling to sub-optimal code.  (Update: that's not what it compiles to, IDK where you got that idea.)

Use 2x [_mm_cvtpd_epi32](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTPD2DQ.html) to get two `__m128i` vectors with ints you want in the low 2 elements of each.  Use [_mm_unpacklo_epi64](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUNPCKLBW:PUNPCKLWD:PUNPCKLDQ:PUNPCKLQDQ.html) to combine those two low halves into one vector with all 4 elements you want.

---

Compiler output from [clang3.8.1 on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang381,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3',source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m128i+pack_double_to_int_badMMX(__m128d+a,+__m128d+b)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm_set_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_pi32(b),+_mm_cvtpd_pi32(a))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A__m128i+pack_double_to_int(__m128d+a,+__m128d+b)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm_unpacklo_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_epi32(a),+_mm_cvtpd_epi32(b))%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).  (Xcode uses clang by default, I think).

```
#include <immintrin.h>

// the good version
__m128i pack_double_to_int(__m128d a, __m128d b) {
    return _mm_unpacklo_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_epi32(a), _mm_cvtpd_epi32(b));
}
    cvtpd2dq        xmm0, xmm0
    cvtpd2dq        xmm1, xmm1
    punpcklqdq      xmm0, xmm1      # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0]
    ret

// the original
__m128i pack_double_to_int_badMMX(__m128d a, __m128d b) {
    return _mm_set_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_pi32(b), _mm_cvtpd_pi32(a));
}
    cvtpd2pi        mm0, xmm1
    cvtpd2pi        mm1, xmm0
    movq2dq xmm1, mm0
    movq2dq xmm0, mm1
    punpcklqdq      xmm0, xmm1      # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0]
      # note the lack of EMMS, because of not using the intrinsic for it
    ret
```

MMX is almost totally useless when SSE2 and later is available; just avoid it.  See the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki for some guides.

Comment: Xcode didn't optimise it away. The disassembly shows _mm_cvtpd_pi32 being used, and _mm_set_epi64 is just using mov to store the values.

Comment: Yep, it works:
_mm_unpacklo_epi64(_mm_cvtpd_epi32(v2dLo), _mm_cvtpd_epi32(v2dHi))