# How to convert int64_t = float * int64_t scalar to vector code and back?

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics

I'd like to convert this scalar code:

```
int64_t res = floatValue * int64Value;
```

using `SSE/SIMD` (built with `-march=nocona`), and later back the value to float:

```
float finalRes = res;
```

Is it possible? I would do somethings like this:

```
__m128 res = _mm_mul_ps(floatValue4, int64Value4);
__m128i res1 = _mm_cvttps_epi64(res);
__m128i res2 = _mm_cvttps_epi64(_mm_movehl_epi64(res, res));
```

but it seems I can't find neither `_mm_cvttps_epi64` or `_mm_movehl_epi64` for the target platform.

Comment: Not sure what are your expectation. Did you try see what compiler generates: https://godbolt.org/z/od7WMoYTG ? From my point of view looks fine.

Comment: @Marek R what do you mean by "fine"? You show me "scalar" code. I need vector one :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144668/how-to-efficiently-perform-double-int64-conversions-with-sse-avx

Comment: @nemequ int64_to_double_full needs _mm_blend_epi16, which is SSE4.1 (and so, don't match my arch target)

Comment: `_mm_blendv_epi16` is easy to emulate on SSE2; instead of `_mm_blendv_epi16(x, 0x88)`, try something like `__m128i tmp = _mm_set_epi16(0, ~0, ~0, ~0, 0, ~0, ~0, ~0); __m128i xL = _mm_or_si128(_mm_and_si128(m, x), _mm_andnot_si128(m, _mm_castpd_si128(_mm_set1_pd(0x0010000000000000))));`.  For 0x33 it's even easier since one of the vectors is all zeros: `_mm_and_si128(xH, _mm_set_epi16(~0, ~0, 0, 0, ~0, ~0, 0, 0))`.

Comment: Are you sure you need 64-bit integers?  In your last question ([How to convert/merge two double (m128d) into one single (m128)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67111388)) your integer constant converted to a compile-time-constant float, which is a lot more efficient than anything you can do with int64.  Until AVX-512, there's no single-instruction FP<->int64 SIMD conversion (only scalar), and no int64 SIMD multiply.

Comment: What you're looking for with `_mm_movehl_epi64(v,v)` is just `_mm_unpackhi_epi64(v,v)`, or if you only want the low half of the result then the `_mm_srli_si128(v, 8)` you were already using also works.

Comment: @PeterCordes the original code use int64_t. Thats because the integrators need that headroom (relative to the settings you place). In loop, both integrators and combs get sum/sub, right?

Comment: I don't really grok the overall algorithm of this code; not one I'm familiar with and you didn't describe it.  Can't you use `double` instead, though?  Scaling by 2^32 is fine for `double`. (Or even `float`; it has enough exponent range, but IDK if it has enough mantissa precision for you).  OTOH, for that serial dependency where you update `s -= pCombs[i]`, integer is nice because it's lower latency for the loop-carried dep chain.  Same for the prefix-sum with `pIntegrators`.  You'd have to unroll more to hide `double` add latency. int64_t add/sub is fine with SIMD, but conversion sucks.

Comment: @PeterCordes its a fir CIC filter (decimator); more about it https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1337.php